# how to check internet connection is available or not in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

can anyone help me, how to check whether internet connection is available or not in my flex application.One more scenario is, if network connection is there but some problem in internet connection how to check internet connection is available or not.

Answer (score 3):

There is a good example here:
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=network_connectivity_1.html

```
import air.net.URLMonitor;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.StatusEvent;

var monitor:URLMonitor;
monitor = new URLMonitor(new URLRequest('http://www.adobe.com'));
monitor.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, announceStatus);
monitor.start();

function announceStatus(e:StatusEvent):void {
    trace("Status change. Current status: " + monitor.available);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer above works but I would like to add that pointing it to your server directly(if you have one) rather than just Adobe will also allow you to monitor your own server and handle it accordingly.

Comment: Note that "above" may not be meaningful, because answers can be sorted differently.

Comment: I fully agree with this. Pinging your own server takes care of two problems at once. It's basically saying if(internetConnection == true  && myServerIsUp == true) ... which is something most people writing service apps are most interested in anyway.

Comment: ... of course, it's not going to be useful to ALL developers. But for those who are writing a service that connects to a proprietary server, then it's a decent way to go.